# C# Excel to Xml and convert it to .net object

Tags: c#, excel

Reading complex excel file content via c# is a bit hard for me. So I am saving as XML my excel file. So I want to read all xml content and convert it to .Net objects.

- worksheets
- rows
- columns

Is there a built in object type for read this xml cotent or is this possible?

Comment: How are you saving the file as XML? Are you just unzipping it and trying to read the raw XML of the excel file? If so, that sounds a LOT harder to me, than just simply using some existing library that is already cabable of doing exactly that (like OpenXML SDK, EPPlus, etc)... (the office xml format is pretty complex, you can look up the documentation online but it is quite a lot reading)

Comment: I am saving xml from Excel save as menu. It saves a new xml document.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ClosedML library - it provides a set of object classes for interpreting OpenXML documents like Word, Excel etc. You can get it from NuGet.